# How to add curly brackets and indent after element in CSS through autocompletion?

Tags: css, intellij-idea, ide, phpstorm, editor

Is it possible to configure the editor that when you type a tag like:

```
body
```

and hit enter/tab, the editor will autocomplete it to:

```
body {

}
```

and indent the selection to where the first property would be typed?

I've looked into `Editor/Codestyle/Stylesheets/CSS` but found nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. A few different options:

1. Type `body {` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. With default settings the IDE will insert missing `}`, add a new line and auto indent.

   This is controlled by options at "Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys".
2. Type `body` and hit <kbd>Ctrl + Shift +Enter</kbd> (or whatever other shortcut you may have there in your Keymap for `Code | Code Completion | Complete Current Statement` action).
3. Write your own snippet (using [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-live-templates.html)) that once expanded will replace the trigger code by inserting the snippet instead.

   Lets assume that you have selected `bb` as the abbreviation for this snippet. Then typing `bb` and hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> (or whatever other expand key you may select for this) will inert the whole block at once.